# iAd fillrate is 0 after 4k requests

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

We launched an app on friday that uses iAds (full screen as well as banners). The dev version shows that iAds are working and itunes connect states that our app is live and receiving ads - but so far there were about 4k requests but fill is still 0.

Is this normal? How can I exclude that there is any technical problem preventing the app to receive ads?

edit: the app is in english and was launched globally (most of the 4k requrests originate from the us)

Comment: we launched globally and most of the 4k requests are originating from the us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an e-mail to apple (that did not get answered whatsover, so I don't know is there a connection) the iAds started appearing and the Fillrate is now around 60%

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not whats happening to you, but I can tell you if the iAd team stops your app receiving Ads (for instance because its aimed at children) then there is no indication and you will see exactly what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen in other places that iAds do not fill in the first few days an app is available.